# n3-chart width not set according to parent width

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

In template file

```
<div class="chart-container">
        <linechart data="data" options="options" mode=""></linechart>
</div>
```

In css file:

```
.chart-container > .chart {
width:800px;
height:500px;
}
```

The svg element is always taking the width of `1333px`.  Are there any options to set height and width? Or am I doing something wrong?
Here is the image:
[image: n3-chart svg width]

Even in the full view I have set width to 800px but the svg element is taking 1333px.
[image: full view chart]

When I resize it  then it works. 
[image: Works on broswer resize]

Comment: I think you haven't set .chart class anywhere in the template.

Comment: The chart class is automatically added by n3-chart.

Answer (score 1):

Change your css definition to  below. Your current css will set size of chart-container that has children of chart but not setting chart width and height itself. So that the chart div will growth to the size of svg.

```
.chart-container, .chart {
  width:800px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Comment: when i resize the broswer to mobile view and again to full view it works but initially it does not work

Comment: Have you changed the css definition as above? Change > (less than) to , (comma). Check whether .chart div correctly set to size according to the css and no other css override its definition.

Comment: Yes I have done as you said.Please look at the images I have updated the question.

Comment: Yes you are right. Could it be because your data is too long so that the svg size expanded beyond div size. Maybe scaling the data will help to resolve this issue.

Comment: But if i set width to 100%, chart is responsive to mobile. It only does not work when I have a sidebar menu as in the first picture.

Comment: Then you should consider sidebar width too. Maybe check n3-chart source code will help you. https://github.com/n3-charts/line-chart/blob/master/dist/line-chart.js